# Why is the js and html code not running the search query?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api

I am trying to use Youtube's api, and run a search query to retrieve the videos found. When I run the js or the html, nothing is printing. The authentication key is correct. When I run the js file all it says is `[Finished in 0.4s]`. When I run the html file nothing shows up.

js file

```
function showResponse(response) {
var responseString = JSON.stringify(response, '', 2);
document.getElementById('response').innerHTML += responseString;
}

function onClientLoad() {
gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', onYouTubeApiLoad);
 }


function onYouTubeApiLoad() {

gapi.client.setApiKey('hidden');

search();
 }

function search() {

var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
    part: 'snippet',
    q: 'dog'
});


request.execute(onSearchResponse);
 }

function onSearchResponse(response) {
showResponse(response);
 }
```

search html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="search.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onClientLoad"     type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <pre id="response"></pre>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you loading page from a server ... localhost or other? Any errors thrown in console?

Comment: I am running on system, and I feel that is the problem. I am using heroku as my server, how would I run it on heroku?

Comment: what does `on system` mean? Opening from `file://` protocol?

Comment: Yes means I am not using any local host or server at the moment

Comment: Then ajax requests will be blocked due to security restrictions in browser. Set up a localhost server on your machine or upload to a server

Comment: How do I upload to a server?

Answer (score 0):

By default the return value for the video link is the video ID inside the json response format.

```
"id": {
  "kind": "youtube#video",
  "videoId": "dgVKzvO5zNc"
}
```

you can filter the json response and create a work around like a link, here is an example:

```
request.execute(function(response) {

    var items = response.result.items;
    for(i in items){
        var vidID = items[i].id.videoId;
        var link = '<a href="http://youtube.com/watch?v='+vidID+'">' + "link"+[i] + '</a><br>';
        document.getElementById('search-container').innerHTML += link;
    }
  });
```

html file

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Search</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="search.js"></script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=googleApiClientReady"></script>
    <div id="buttons"><input id="query" value='cats' type="text"/><button id="search-button" onclick="search()" >Search</button></label>
    </div>
    <div id="search-container">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```